Bidding game with asymmetric information

Players $A,B$ are bidding for the outcome of 200 coinflips $X\sim Bin(200,1/2)$.
The winning player gains $X$ minus their bid.
Player $B$ has advantage of knowing the outcome of 20 randomly selected coins. (Let's call this number $K\sim Bin(20,1/2)$)
Upon equal bids, the winner is picked randomly.
This is a first price auction and the players want to maximize expected payoffs.


What are the optimal strategies/expectations under simultaneous bidding?

My attempt:
restrict ourselves to pure strategies.

$A$'s strategy profile is just the their bid $a\in[0,99]$

$B$'s strategy profile is the set of (likely nondecreasing) assignments $b(k)\colon k\to \left[0,\dfrac{180}{2}+k-1\right]$

A's best response to $b(k)$:
$$\begin{align*}BR_A(b(k)) &=\text{argmax}_a\,\,  E_{k\sim K} \,\,  \begin{cases}\left(k +\dfrac{180}{2}-a\right)  & \text{if }a>b(k) \\ \dfrac{1}{2} \left(k +\dfrac{180}{2}-a\right) &  \text{if }a=b(k)\\ 0 &\text{else}\end{cases}\\
&=\text{argmax}_a \left[
\mathbf 1_{a=b(T)} P(K=T) \dfrac{1}{2}\left(k +\dfrac{180}{2}-a\right) + \sum_{k<T}P(K=k) \left(k+\dfrac{180}{2}-a\right)\right]\end{align*}$$
where $T(b(k),a)$ (for "threshold") is defined as $T:=\min_k \colon b(k)\geq a$. In other words, given $B$'s bid curve $b(k)$, $A$ must decide the upper bound $k^*$ of possible $K$-values for which they want to outbid $B$. Once $k^*$ is decided upon, the actual bid $a^*$ is just $b(k^*-1)+1$

$B$'s best response to $a$ is $a+1$ (or $a$ to split) as long as $$\dfrac{180}{2}+k - (a+1)>0\iff a < \dfrac{180}{2}+k-1 \iff k>a+1 -\dfrac{180}{2}$$ and staying out otherwise. This corresponds to $T(a)=a+1 -(180/2)$

I'm not sure that this is the right thing to do, but I'm compelled to plug in this $T(a)$ into $A$'s best response and find the maximizing $a$. It feels like the range of $k$ values for which $B$ wants to outbid $A$ should meet the range of $k$s for which $A$ wants to outbid $B$, or else there is arbitrage.



I'd appreciate any ideas on what would happen if $B$ makes a bid that is visible to $A$. It feels like this would be a much harder problem, as it opens up mixed bluffing strategies for $B$.



Perhaps include more details, such as this is a first price auction and players want to maximize expected payoffs.



Do you have reason to believe that an 'elegant' analytical solution exists, e.g. is this an exercise from a book or class? An alternative to an elegant solution would be something that a computer program can find using trial and error, which seems very possible here given the limited strategy space.


The question was allegedly asked in a trading interview. It wouldn't be surprising for it to not have a nice solution. My hope is to find a way to confirm the intuition of adverse selection: that A can only ever win bids that have negative EV.

"A can only ever win bids that have negative EV." If, instead of asking for a complete solution, you post that conjecture as a question, users here should be able disprove it.
